# Update-Database fails on production server

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I've enabled migrations for my ASP.NET MVC project. Migrations work perfectly on localhost. However I get the following exception after deploying it to the server:

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set `DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` to true to enable automatic migration.
>   [View Stack Trace](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=schHpMR2)

There are no pending migrations, though. Adding a new migration just creates empty `Up()` & `Down()`

What could be the reason it doesn't work on the server? I've tried deleting the migrations folder, re-enabling migrations, deleting the database, and let EF do it afresh. The tables get created, but I end up with that exception.

**Update:**
Another thing I noticed is, when I delete the migration folder but not the database, and enable migrations, it only adds a Configuration.cs file, when it's supposed to add another file too (initialcreate.cs)

Comment: which entity framework you are using? Have you tried setting AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true ?

Comment: Have you applied the empty migration with update-database? That should align the model with the snapshot.

Comment: @SimpleMan I tagged it. If you wanted to know the version it's 6.1.1

Comment: @SimpleMan Oh and I dint want to enable automatic migrations, so  I dint bother trying it out. I dont think it's a good idea to use automatic migrations on production

Comment: @SteveGreene just tried, dint work

Comment: If its VS2013 and SQL Server, you could try comparing schemas http://www.techbubbles.com/sql-server/schema-compare-for-sql-server-in-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: @SteveGreene I can't do that. I'm using VS Professional https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833435%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: How did you create the database on the server? You could try to use the scripts from the localhost. Also you could generate the scripts and make a diff to understand the difference. Also, do you have the same version of SQL Server on localhost and server? It's some time that I don't read EF source code but there is the concept of manifest that influences the data type selection behaviour (i.e. varchar(max) instead of text).

Comment: @bubi the database was created using web deploy. It does a `update-database` when the application first runs at the server. I'm using SQL Server 2012 in the server and at localhost.

Answer (score -1):

This happens when you are doing tow different query on the same list of objects on the same time without using `.toList`

example :

you can create context and get a list of testObjects then edit one of this objects then save changes

```
var objectsList = context.testObjects.where(x=>x.whatever=true)
objectsList[0].whatever2="asd"
context.SaveChanges()
```

the above code will pass the compailer and it will fail while running, to solve this it should be as below

```
    var objectsList = context.testObjects.where(x=>x.whatever=true).ToList()
    objectsList[0].whatever2="asd"
    context.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: If this was the issue, it wouldn't have worked on localhost either.